# Decidability of theory of modules over a ring of finite representation type

Tags: rt.representation-theory, model-theory, modules, decidability, artin-ring

I have read from Mike Prest's model theory for modules (London lecture note series) chapter 17 that a Ring of finite representation type has a decidable theory of modules.  Here decidability was defined in the usual sense for theories : A theory is decidable if there is an effective method that decides whether the formula is in the theory or not.

I could not find a relevant literature or paper where this statement has been proved. I needed this result to assert a crucial proposition in my thesis. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a follow up question, are there specific papers investigating the syntactic completeness of the theory of modules over Artin Algebras? I can't seem to find much literature for this topic.

Thank you very much

Comment: The paper DECIDABILITY FOR THEORIES OF MODULES by 
FRANCHISE POINT AND MIKE PREST Journal of the London Mathematical SocietyVolume s2-38, Issue 2 p. 193-206 seems to indicate it is because the theories of finitely presented modules and all modules are  the  same. I guess the point must be that you can check truth in the indecomposables and there are only finitely many.

Comment: Thank you very much . The given reasoning makes complete sense to me. I will try to provide a proof in that direction.